# Unable to build a multi-level menu using mat menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, stackblitz

I am using Angular 8 with Angular Material to build a multi-level menu that is 3 levels deep.

E.g.

> One      ->      Two      ->      Three

StackBlitz Example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-sidenav-multi-level-menu-u93fqt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Does anyone know how I can solve this? I want to stop the list of items from closing automatically, i.e. to display item `Three`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the mat-list-item Element from the submenus and place matMenuTriggerFor on the button with the mat-menu-item decorator instead:

```html
<mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2">Two</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Your full example:
https://dynamic-sidenav-multi-level-menu-cnarmb.stackblitz.io